# Analog Perl crypt() function in node.js

Tags: perl, node.js

Looking for Perl crypt() function in node.js.

```
perl -e 'print crypt("", "12345")'
```

return: 12UFlHxel6uMM
Looking the same in node.js

Answer (score 1):

There is a powerful and well supported node package for password encryption - [bcrypt](https://npmjs.org/package/bcrypt).

What you want is:

```
var bcrypt = require('bcrypt');
var hash = bcrypt.hashSync('', '12345');
```

See [bcrypt API Docs](https://github.com/ncb000gt/node.bcrypt.js#api) for more info.

---

**Updated.** You can also use [Node crypto module](http://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html). In this case you may use [`crypto.pbkdf2` method](http://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_crypto_pbkdf2_password_salt_iterations_keylen_callback). I newer used it myself, so I can't guarantee its stability, usability and security.

I also can't guarantee than either bcrypt or crypto uses the same algorithm for password hashing as Perl crypt method. So the result may be different from Perl crypt even if salt is the same.

Though Node crypto is a build-in module, I strongly recommend you to use bcrypt if possible, because its more secure.

Comment: Doesn't work. Salt must be generated via bcrypt.genSaltSync; Can't use '12345' as salt.

Comment: I've asked about Perl crypt() not a Phyton.

Comment: Anyway, if you want **exactly** the same function then you shall use [`child_process.exec`](http://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_exec_command_options_callback) to call Perl directly from Node.

Answer (score 0):

You may get something out of this library: https://npmjs.org/package/crypt