# node.js DES encryption for unix password hashes not working like mkpasswd

Tags: javascript, node.js, ubuntu, encryption, cryptography

I've been trying to create ubuntu user password hashes inside a node.js application.

I would call the [crypt(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/crypt.3.html) function, but I have trouble finding a way of doing that from inside node. Is that easily done? Afaik, it's rather easy in python (see [analog-perl-crypt-function-in-node-js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14185710/analog-perl-crypt-function-in-node-js)).

That is why I am using `mkpasswd -s -m des '#{pass}'` inside an `exec` call, fetch the `stdout` contents to have access to the hash and pass it to `useradd -p #{hash}` for automated user generation. I am aware that this way the password is visible in the process listing. I want to avoid that.

Common output for a working command like this would be

```
me@server:~$ mkpasswd -m des 'test'
Xnhhy1HbwhA1k
```

A hash like this is what i want to achieve inside my app.

I have been trying to use `crypto`, `bcrypt` or `cryptojs` to create the hash inside the application, thus avoiding any visibility on the server process list. But every `DES` hash I create is not working.

For example, `cryptojs` with the following code gets it slightly wrong:

```coffee
  salt = 'This is a salt'
  result = crypto.DES .encrypt 'test', salt
  console.log result
```

```bsh
  Output: K0dLSddKUcmkOaoC
```

Am I even correct in attempting to use DES?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Am I even correct in attempting to use DES?

No, you are not. `crypt()` is based on DES, but it is not DES, and it is not even based on a standard DES implementation.

[Wikipedia explains at length](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crypt_%28C%29#Traditional_DES-based_scheme):

> The traditional implementation (*of the `crypt()` function*) uses a modified form of the DES algorithm. The user's password is truncated to eight characters, and those are coerced down to only 7-bits each; this forms the 56-bit DES key. That key is then used to encrypt an all-bits-zero block, and then the ciphertext is encrypted again with the same key, and so on for a total of 25 DES encryptions. A 12-bit salt is used to perturb the encryption algorithm, so standard DES implementations can't be used to implement `crypt()`. The salt and the final ciphertext are encoded into a printable string in a form of base64.

If `crypt()` were implemented in the fashion you're assuming, it would be possible to decrypt a password by using the salt as a key. This would make it entirely ineffective as a password hash.

Comment: This algorithm sounds ridiculously weak – do not ever use it.

Comment: The algorithm is imperfect, particularly as it is restricted to 8-character passwords, but it is not believed to be fundamentally flawed - any attack on it would amount to a known-plaintext attack on iterated DES, which I don't believe exists. (The function is still flawed, though, as the entire password space can be brute-forced.)

Comment: (TL;DR: Do not use DES password hashes.)

Comment: It's worth adding that searching through the whole 56-bit DES keyspace takes less than 24 hours with [current hardware](http://picocomputing.com/sc-series/sc-5) – the fact that the key consists of only ASCII characters makes the search even faster, at least by an order of magnitude.

Comment: Thank you for explaining this. It sounds like a method lost in time, and the sources on DES mention the attack vectors that are now possible. I should probably change my who approach, since the `useradd` man page has this to say about the issue:  `The encrypted password, as returned by crypt(3). The default is to disable the password. Note: This option is not recommended because the password (or encrypted password) will be visible by users listing the processes.` Any ideas on automating adding a user (with a password) to the system from node that does not involve this trickery?

Comment: @arvidkahl you could better post the question to SO affiliates [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Server Vault](http://serverfault.com/). Those sites handle admin questions.